# finding complexity using induction

Tags: complexity-theory, induction

I was asked to prove:

for every n>=n0 and `T(n) = T(an) + T(bn) + n` for n>n0, a+b<1, its complexity is `T(n) = O(n)`.

Hint: prove by induction that: `T(n) ≤ cn` for a suitable c.

I wanted to know **how to prove by induction** in this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we postulate the inequality to be true for `an` and `bn`, then

[image]

Now we don't know the exact relationship between this constant and `c`; but if we look at the case where

[image]

But `a + b` can be arbitrarily close to 1, meaning that `c` would be arbitrarily large. This kinda defeats the point of O-notation since the constant must be finite. Therefore we take the lower bound:

[image]

Hence we've found the range of `c` for which the postulate can be true. The lower bound of 1 is because your domain `n >= n0` means that `T(n0) = n0`. Here the constant is 1 so `c` must be at least 1 to satisfy the postulated initial bound. This also restricts the values of `a` and `b` to be positive.

But for the postulate to be true, `a, b` can take *any* value in `[0, 1)`, meaning that if the bound is correct for `T(n)` then it is also correct for any larger parameter e.g.`T(n + 1)`.

So we know that:

1. The hypothesis is true for `n = n0`
2. If true for `n` then also true for `n + 1`

Hence by induction, `T(n) <= cn` for any `n >= n0`, where `c` satisfies the bounds from earlier.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question, why T(n0)=n0?

Comment: @Rotem the other terms `T(an0)` and `T(bn0)` both have parameters `< n0`, and because you say `T(n)` is defined for `n >= n0`, we take those to be zero